# qTip render error? and advice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert, qtip

I'm using [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/) and i noticed that when the tip is visible and a javascript alert is triggered the qtip does not disappear after the alert has been dismissed.

Is there any fix?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do an `alert()` (or `prompt()`) the browser's state is essentially frozen, waiting for the dialogue to be dismissed.

If you want to stop this, use a [custom modal](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog).

Comment: I fixed this problem by removing the alert because i realised that the qtip replace the alert, but i found that when the element that qtip is linked to is removed you get the same error, so i just put in the code: "$('.qtip').remove()"